# I forgot how to include PHP files (such as navbar.php, header.php)

Tags: php, html, css, include

I've forgotten how to include a php file, I use includes to style my site.

Here's the code I'm currently running:

```
<?php include ("/style/v1/navbar.php"); ?>
```

That should link to my navbar, which is located in style/v1/""

It's not showing my navbar, all the CSS is in one file, which is used in both the navbar.php and index.php. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 3):

A nice way to do includes is like this, assuming that the `/style/` folder is in your root folder:

```
<?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/style/v1/navbar.php"; ?>
```

With this syntax you can use the same code from anywhere in the site, rather than having to work out relative paths on each page.

(If the `/style/` folder is not in the root folder, just adjust `/style/v1/navbar.php` to reflect its actual location in relation to the root folder.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a `/` at the beginning of your path.

When using `include()`/`require()`, file paths are on disk, not the document root of your web server.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be something stupid on my part. ^_^ It's getting late here.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php include ("style/v1/navbar.php"); ?>
```

Just remove the initial slash '/'.

Answer (score 1):

> if you have a problem with php include, this should help:
>   [click here](http://w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<?php include('style/folder/header.php'); ?>
Hello World!
<?php include('style/folder/footer.php'); ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slash before the path:

`<?php include('style/v1/navbar.php'); ?>`

When using `include` it can be a good idea to also use `dirname(__FILE__)` to refer to the absolute path of where your PHP app is hosted. Thus,

`<?php include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . 'style/v1/navbar.php');` ?>

This means that when you're moving your web app from one server to another, or moving the location of certain files, you're less likely to have problems.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are following ways to include file

```
1. include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/style/v1/navbar.php");
2. include(__DIR__."style/v1/navbar.php");
3. include('style/v1/navbar.php');
```